# Typeerror error.json is not a function in firefox

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I am not able to understand what is the error about. My code is working fine in Google Chrome and Microsoft Edge. But it does not work in Mozilla Firefox. Here is the screenshot for the same. I am creating my project in Angular 2

angular-cli: 1.0.0-beta.14
node: 6.5.0
os: win32 x64

[image]

Comment: Can you post the code that's generating this error?

Comment: Please visit this site to see the code.https://github.com/MateenKadwaikar/Groceries

Comment: @Actorclavilis problem solved. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the problem and I fixed that now it is working as expected.

I put a header for

> ```
>  private headers: Headers = new Headers({
>         'Content-Type': 'application/json',
>         'Accept': 'application/json'
>     });
> ```

and called it in my service call.

Answer (score 1):

I got this error, as well, even though I set my headers. After digging around for hours I realized I had my express router set up for a `.get` instead of a `.post`. Hope this helps someone solve a stupid mistake quickly.